# Retrieve tables and table data from ini.bak file

Tags: sql, mysql

I have changed computers. Therefore i have lost access to my `MySQL` database. However, i was able to get the `my 2013-05-09 1145.ini.bak` file. Will i be able to retrieve all the folders and the data that was in from this file.

I have tried googling for this, but left with no hope. If this cann't be done, then suggest ways i could copy the database and its content.

I was going through the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.htmlbut left with no hope.

How can i get this done?

Note: I found a folder that contains `.frm` and `db.opt` file. Will these be helpful.

Comment: I assume you just tried to bring down the server, put your ini.bak file as my.ini and then started mysql again? And yes, you do need the frm files, but that won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to turn on the old machine and make a database dump.

If it was a myisam database, you can copy the directory with the .frm files.

With innodb tables I was not able to find another solution but dumping the data with mysqldump.